# Retrieve a list of nodes of an XML file in Java

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I have an XML file as below

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="catalog.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE catalog SYSTEM "catalog.dtd">
<catalog>
   <product description="Cardigan Sweater" product_image="cardigan.jpg">
      <catalog_item gender="Men's">
         <item_number>QWZ5671</item_number>
         <price>39.95</price>
         <size description="Medium">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
         </size>
         <size description="Large">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
         </size>
      </catalog_item>
      <catalog_item gender="Women's">
         <item_number>RRX9856</item_number>
         <price>42.50</price>
         <size description="Small">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
         </size>
         <size description="Medium">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
         </size>
      </catalog_item>
   </product>
</catalog>
```

What is the best way to extract all the nodes in a specific name (catalog_item) and create a List(list of Catalog items) in java.
Note that the XML would consist of any list of nodes where I should be able to specify a name of node and extract all the nodes of that name to make a list.

Comment: [XPath?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/xpath.html)

Comment: I guess you can use [`Document.getElementsByTagName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#getElementsByTagName-java.lang.String-)

Comment: Document.getElementsByTagName("catalog_item"); gives a list of required nodes which is easy to iterate and extract data furthermore. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use a HTML parser like [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) Download and add the jar file to your project. Then do this.

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements elements = document.select("catalog_item"); //get everything under catalog_item

for (Element element : elements) {
    String number = element.getElementsByTag("price").text(); // select specific tag
    // select rest of info from tags you need
}
```

Comment: if `Document.select` follows basic XPath syntax, then it isn't guarenteed that it will do the selection properly. Also why are you doing this much effort for a post where OP put no effort in.

Comment: I'm not familiar with XPath but with Jsoup this should work properly. I will concede to your second point though.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to post my approach in detail to help someone who needed help with the same scenario.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new File("C:/ProductItems.xml"));
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

//Reading all the catelog items and store in a NodeList
NodeList catItemList=doc.getElementsByTagName("catalog_item");

if(catItemList.getLength()>0){      //if there are catelog items 
    for(int itemIndex=0 ; itemIndex < catItemList.getLength() ; itemIndex++){
            Node catalogItem=catItemList.item(itemIndex);

            if (catalogItem.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                 Element eElement = (Element) catalogItem;
                 String gender = eElement.getAttribute("gender");
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code for doing node extraction in vtd-xml. the extraction logic is what you need to fill in...

```
import com.ximpleware.*;

public class retrieveNodes{
    public  static  void main(String s[]) throws VTDException,java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException,java.io.IOException{
        VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
        vg.setLCDepth(5);
        if (!vg.parseFile("input.xml", false))
            return;
        VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
        AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
        ap.selectXPath("/catalog/product/catalog_item");
        int i=0;
        while((i=ap.evalXPath())!=-1){
           if (vn.toElement(VTDNav.FIRST_CHILD,"itemNumber")){
               int j=vn.getText();
               if (j!=-1)
                  System.out.println("text node ==>"+vn.toString(j);
               vn.toElement(VTDNav.PARENT);
           }
        }

    }

}
```